# copying and assignment

Tags: c++

Could somebody explain me the difference between copying and assignment?

```
SomeClass a;
SomeClass b = a; // assignment
SomeClass c(a); // assignment
b = c; // copying
```

but what is the difference, why there are two different constructions in the language?

Comment: What you call "assignment" is actually called "initialization", and what you call "copying" is called "assignment".

Comment: `SomeClass a();` -- That's a function declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying is for initializing new objects by copying the contents of existing ones, assignment is for overwriting existing objects with the contents of other objects - the two are very different things. In particular, this

```
SomeClass a;
SomeClass b = a;
```

is *copy initialization* - you're copying `a` to create a new SomeClass called `b` using syntax of the form

```
T x = y;
```

This has the effect of invoking `SomeClass`'s copy constructor (assuming there is one and it's accessible). The compiler-generated default copy constructor would do a memberwise copy of `a`; you can replace it with your own as needed, e.g.

```
SomeClass(const SomeClass& rhs)
: x(rhs.x)
{}
```

(Note that this is a very boring example, as it just does what the default memberwise copy constructor might.)

Moving on, this

```
SomeClass c(a);
```

is *direct initialization* using the copy constructor. It will generally have the same effect as the above, but this is worth a read:

http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm

Also, see here:

http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/001.htm

Your final case, namely

```
b = c;
```

is assignment. The semantics of this should generally be to overwrite `b` with the contents of `c` (although some things, such as `std::auto_ptr`, have strange assignment semantics, so watch out). To implement your own assignment operator, you write something like this (note that this is a very boring example, as it just does what the default memberwise assignment operator might):

```
SomeClass& operator=(const SomeClass& rhs)
{
    x = rhs.x;
    return *this;
}
```

In practice, however, you have to be careful about exception safety in situations like this, which leads to things like the popular copy-and-swap idiom for implementing assignment operators. See here:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Copy-and-swap

Answer (score 3):

Initialization only happens once, when the object is created. If by copying you mean calling the copy constructor, than copying is a form of initialization. Assignment can happen any number of times.

Now, on to your example, all of those are wrong:

```
SomeClass a();
```

This declares a method called `a` which takes no parameters and returns an object `SomeClass`.

```
SomeClass b = a; // actually copy constructor & initialization of b
SomeClass c(a); // same
```

If `a` were a `SomeClass` object, these two would be initialization, and it calls the copy constructor - `SomeClass::SomeClass(const SomeClass&)`. They are equivalent.

```
b = c; // assignment
```

If `c` is a `SomeClass` object, **this** is assignment. It callse `SomeClass::operator =(const SomeClass&)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is initialization (but it calls the copy constructor):

```
SomeClass b = a;
```

So is this:

```
SomeClass c(a);
```

This is assignment:

```
b = c;
```

Oh, and this [isn't an initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse):

```
SomeClass a();
```

Comment: difference - assignment works on `already created` object while copy on newly constructed object which did not exist before.

Answer (score 1):

Initializations initialize a previously uninitialized object. Assignments, on the other hand, overwrite an already initialized object and may have to destroy existing state. These are different operations; while they usually have the same outcome for the object on the LHS, they are not semantically equivalent.